# Insert a date from boostrap datepicker into MySQL date field does not work

Tags: php, mysql, date, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have tried so many possible solutions and it's just not working for me.  I have the following code:

```
<div class="bootstrap-iso">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
               <!-- datepicker code begins -->
               <div class="form-group"> <!-- Date input -->
                   <label class="control-label" for="date">Closing Date</label>
                   <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="YYYY-  MM-DD" type="date"/>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>    
    </div>
```

Then I have the follownig:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var date_input=$('input[name="date"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
        var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
        var options={
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            container: container,
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
        };
        date_input.datepicker(options);
    })
</script>
```

In my class I have the following code:

```
$newVacancy_stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO vacancies (roleID, shortTitle, longTitle, roleDescription, roleResponsibilities, roleRequirements, createdBy, creationDate, publishDate, closeDate) VALUES (:roleID, :shortTitle, :longTitle, :roleDescription, :roleResponsibilities, :roleRequirements, :createdBy, NOW(), NOW(), ' . $closingDate . '))');
```

I convert my posted date with this:

```
$closingDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['date']));
```

Then I call my function:

```
$addVacancy = addNewVacancyInternal($roleID, $shortTitle, $longTitle, $roleDescription, $roleResponsibilities, $roleRequirements, $createdBy, $closingDate);
```

It does not insert the record into the DB.  As soon as I take the date out (not inserting the date) it insert the record.  Any suggestions please?

Comment: Check what value you are getting in $_POST['date']. Tell us the value.

Answer (score 1):

```
$db->prepare('INSERT INTO vacancies (roleID, ...., publishDate, closeDate) 
                             VALUES (:roleID, .... NOW(), :closingDate))');
```

and pass `$closingDate` with the rest of the named parameters.

Comment: `$closingDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['date']));`

Comment: `$addVacancy = addNewVacancyInternal($roleID, $shortTitle, $longTitle, $roleDescription, $roleResponsibilities, $roleRequirements, $createdBy, $closingDate);`  `$newVacancy_stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO vacancies (roleID, shortTitle, longTitle, roleDescription, roleResponsibilities, roleRequirements, createdBy, creationDate, publishDate, closeDate) VALUES (:roleID, :shortTitle, :longTitle, :roleDescription, :roleResponsibilities, :roleRequirements, :createdBy, NOW(), NOW(), :closingDate))');`

Comment: `$newVacancy_stmt->bindParam(':closingDate', $closingDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);` `$addNewVacancy = $newVacancy_stmt->execute();`  Is still not working thanks.

Comment: No, as soon as I insert the record without the date it insert.

Comment: are there any errors when you insert it with date? Also enable query log and check how the query looks when it reaches the db.

Comment: How do I enable query log please?  PDO give me now errors.  I have this `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); `

Comment: MySQL error log:  `2017-06-16T02:52:43.302100Z    2 Connect ### on ### using TCP/IP 2017-06-16T02:52:43.303103Z     2 Quit`

Comment: Got it, that was one to many ")" at the end of the query:  `$newVacancy_stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO vacancies (roleID, shortTitle, longTitle, roleDescription, roleResponsibilities, roleRequirements, createdBy, creationDate, publishDate, closeDate) VALUES (:roleID, :shortTitle, :longTitle, :roleDescription, :roleResponsibilities, :roleRequirements, :createdBy, NOW(), NOW(), :closingDate)');`